# JPA / EclipseLink: Joined WHERE query does not give expected result

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

Now that's very confusing... I have a JPA entity `Order` that references an entity `User`. The User can be either buyer or seller of the Order.

Because both buyer and seller can enter additional information for an order, I moved that to an extra entity `OrderUserData`. There might or might not be a corresponding `OrderUserData` object, but IF one exists, the user should only be able to see the entry they created (based on USER_ID) and not the one of the other party.

The entities look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ORDER")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SELLER_ID")
    private User seller;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BUYER_ID")
    private User buyer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<OrderUserData> userData = new ArrayList<>();

   //..
}
```

--

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ORDER_USERDATA")
public class OrderUserData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;

    private String comment;
  //...
}
```

( `User` is not very exciting, just ID and basic name fields )

Now when I'm trying to select the appropriate data to display in the website, I have a problem:

```
String qry = "SELECT o FROM Order o LEFT JOIN o.userData ud "
            + " WHERE (o.seller.id = :userId OR o.buyer.id = :userId)"
            + " AND ( ud.user IS NULL OR ud.user.id = :userId )";
    TypedQuery<Order> query = em.createQuery(qry, Order.class);

    query.setParameter("userId", userId);
```

Let's say I execute this, setting `userId` to 2:

My Database looks like this:

```
ORDER
=====
ID    SELLER_ID    BUYER_ID
1     1            2
2     2            3
3     3            1

ORDER_USERDATA
===============
ID     ORDER_ID    USER_ID    COMMENT
1      1           1          Comment that only user 1 should see
2      1           2          Comment that only user 2 should see
```

But unlike you would expect, when executing the above query, both records are included in the `userData` list! It seems like JPA is executing two queries (despite the EAGER fetch) and ignoring the WHERE on the second one. Why is that? And what other solution than to loop through the `userData` list on Java level and kick out the  entry that the appropriate user should not see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to load *OrderUserData* objects inside an *Order* object using a query. Maybe you're confusing the ORM functionality, mapping rows in the database to Java objects, with the query functionality.
Mapping means 1-1 correspondence between rows and objects, hence *Order* objects always contain all *OrderUserData* objects for each *OrderUserData* row related to *Order* rows.
The fetch type is just a loading strategy, determining at which time are the related objects fetched, as soon as the containing object is loaded (EAGER) or as soon as the contained objects are accessed (LAZY).
You can obtain your list issuing a query on *OrderUserData* objects with the proper filters and getting *Order* objects from each of them, i.e.

> SELECT ud FROM OrderUserData ud  WHERE (ud.order.seller.id = :userId
>   OR ud.order.buyer.id = :userId) AND ( ud.user IS NULL OR ud.user.id =
>   :userId )

Comment: Thx, that really works! The only thing I don't understand is why? :) 
`WHERE (ud.order.seller.id = :userId ...` isn't that the same thing just the other way round? 
This is selecting from OrderUserData while also applying a WHERE condition on a different entity (namely the Order that is attached to the OrderUserData). So why does it work when traversing from ud => order but not the other way round?

Answer (score 1):

your query seems to work well as it selects properly Order entity. Then JPA fetch all the OrderUserData child of the selected Order : that's because oneToMany join is not filtered. 
I don't think it is possible to modelize pre-filtered oneToMany with eclipseLink (like Hibernate @FILTER), so you should remove it and map orderUserDataId field only. Then you can fetch your entities in 1 query, but they will not be linked

```
SELECT o, ud FROM Order o, o.userData ud WHERE (o.seller.id = :userId OR o.buyer.id = :userId) AND ( ud.orderUserDataId = o.id and (ud.user IS NULL OR ud.user.id = :userId) )";
```

On the other hand, if the oneToMany is required by other use cases, then you can create 2 different Order entities :

- 1 "OrderLight" without the oneToMany
- 1 "OrderFull"  with the oneToMany, derived from OrderLight.

Answer (score 0):

While user3580357 and remigio have already given the correct answer as to why this doesn't work, might I suggest that you create a **view** on database level.

Something like (might need to be adapted for your needs or RDBMS):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW 
  ORDER_WITH_USERDATA 
AS 
  SELECT o.*, oud.* 
FROM ORDER o
LEFT JOIN ORDER_USERDATA oud
  ON o.id = oud.order_id
```

This will essentially give you two different "logical" records for every order. You can then create an additional JPA entity that works on this view and do your SELECT/WHERE... without needing to (LEFT)JOIN at all.